# python multiprocessing.Process executes a wrong target (packaged with py2exe)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, py2exe

i have a problem.

i using python(2.7.7, 32bit) and py2exe(0.6.9) on Windows7(64bit).

my application structure such as the following:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def child():
  print "child"

def main():
  print "main"
  p = Process(target=child)
  p.start()
  p.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

(1)result before packaged:

```
main
child
```

(2)result after packaged:

```
main
main
main
...(forever)
```

i want to get (1) after packaging.

please tell me how to get (1) after packaging.

love.

Comment: try calling [`multiprocessing.freeze_support()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need a call to `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` when packaging a Python script into an executable for use on Windows. This call should come just after `if __name__ == '__main__':` before actually calling `main()`.

[Link to multiprocessing.freeze docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support)