# Multiprocessing python within frozen script

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, multiprocessing, cx-freeze

I am trying to compile a script utilizing `multiprocessing` into a Windows executable. At first I ran into the same issue as [Why python executable opens new window instance when function by multiprocessing module is called on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33970690/why-python-executable-opens-new-window-instance-when-function-by-multiprocessing) when I compiled it into an executable. Following the accepted answer I adjusted my script such that

```
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
# my functions
if __name__ == "__main__":
    freeze_support()
    # my script
```

And this again works perfectly when run as a script. However, when I compile and run it I encounter:

[image: Error message]

Where I've underlined in green part of the error. This specific line refers to

```
freeze_support()
```

in my script. Furthermore, it is not actually encountered on this line, but when my script goes to multiprocess which is something like:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function, args=[my_list])
p.start()
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function, args=[my_list])
p1.start()
p.join()
p1.join()
```

Is this an error in the multiprocessing module (specifically line 148) or am I misunderstanding the answer I linked, or something else?

I'll also note that the script does work correctly when compiled, but you have to click "OK" on an error message for every multiprocess that is spawned (quite a lot) and every error message is exactly the same. Would this mean i am improperly ending the process with the `p.join()`?

I've also tried the solution at [Python 3.4 multiprocessing does not work with py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115428/python-3-4-multiprocessing-does-not-work-with-py2exe) which recommends adding

```
multiprocessing.set_executable(os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix, 'pythonw.exe'))
```

to your script, yet this causes an error in the script form (not even compiled yet) of:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Thanks for the help!

freeze_support documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to have been a problem for quite some time - I found references going back to 2014, at least. Since it appears to be harmless, the general recommendation is to suppress the error by replacing `sys.stdout` (and `sys.stderr`, which is flushed on the next line) with a dummy. Try this:

```py
import os
import sys
from multiprocessing import freeze_support

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.stdout is None:
        sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    freeze_support()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not an issue of the multiprocessing library or py2exe per se but a side effect of the way you run the application. The [py2exe documentation](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/StderrLog) contains some discussion on this topic:

> A program running under Windows can be of two types: a console
>   program or a windows program. A console program is one that runs in
>   the command prompt window (cmd). Console programs interact with users
>   using three standard channels: standard input, standard output and
>   standard error […].
>
> As opposed to a console application, a windows application interacts
>   with the user using a complex event-driven user interface and
>   therefore has no need for the standard channels whose use in such
>   applications usually results in a crash.

Py2exe will work around these issues automatically in some cases, but at least one of your processes has no attached standard output: `sys.stdout` is `None`), which means that `sys.stdout.flush()` is `None.flush()`, which yields the error you are getting. The documentation linked above has an easy fix that redirects all outputs to files.

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open(“my_stdout.log”, “w”)
sys.stderr = open(“my_stderr.log”, “w”)
```

Simply add those lines at the entry point of your processes. There is also a relevant documentation page on the [interactions between Py2Exe and subprocesses](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2ExeSubprocessInteractions).